# How does C know the end of my string?

Tags: c, string

I have a program in which I wanted to remove the spaces from a string. I wanted to find an elegant way to do so, so I found the following (I've changed it a little so it could be better readable) code [in a forum](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/21071/what-function-can-delete-a-space-in-a-string):

```cpp
char* line_remove_spaces (char* line)
{
    char *non_spaced = line;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(line); i++)
    {
        if ( line[i] != ' ' )
        {
            non_spaced[j] = line[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return non_spaced;
}
```

As you can see, the function takes a string and, using the same allocated memory space, selects only the non-spaced characters. It works!

Anyway, according to Wikipedia, a string in C is a "[Null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)". I always thought this way and everything was good. But the problem is: we put no "null-character" in the end of the `non_spaced` string. And somehow the compiler knows that it ends at the last character changed by the "non_spaced" string. How does it know?

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler knows it"? You're changing it at runtime, compile process is long over.

Comment: For what it's worth, `strlen(line)` will recalculate the length of the string every time. This is a non-trivial calculation, and should not be done on every loop iteration. You would do much better to calculate it once and store the it: `size_t len = strlen(line); for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)`. (Also, all the variables you have as `int`s should technically be type `size_t`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does not happen by magic. You have in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(line); i++)
              ^^
```

The loop index `i` runs till `strlen(line)` and at this index there is a nul character in the character array and this gets copied as well. As a result your end result has nul character at the desired index.

If you had

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
              ^^
```

then you had to put the nul character manually as:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
{
    if ( line[i] != ' ' )
    {
        non_spaced[j] = line[i];
        j++;
    }
}
// put nul character
line[j] = 0;
```

Comment: the null character would be '\0' not ' '

Comment: @xFortyFourx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705968/what-is-value-of-eof-and-0-in-c

Comment: Hello codaddict, I'm not sure why you posted that thread. 
The ASCII value of '\0' = 0
ASCII value of ' ' (empty/white space) = 32

Comment: The last line `line[j] = 0;` should be `non_spaced[j] = 0;`. And @KBN, this code is to remove the spaces from the given string, read the OP's question and you'll know :)

Comment: @starriet haha, that's 10years old, I've no idea what's going on,.

Answer (score 8):

Others have answered your question already, but here is a faster, and perhaps clearer version of the same code:

```
void line_remove_spaces (char* line)
{
  char* non_spaced = line;

  while(*line != '\0')
  {
    if(*line != ' ')
    {
      *non_spaced = *line;
      non_spaced++;
    }

    line++;
  }

  *non_spaced = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop uses `<= strlen` so you will copy the null terminator as well (which is at `i == strlen(line)`).

Answer (score 1):

You could try it. Debug it while it is processing a string containing only one space: `" "`.  Watch carefully what happens to the index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it "knows"? The most likely scenario is that you're simply having luck with your undefined behavior, and that there is a `'\0'`-character after the valid bytes of `line` end.

It's also highly likely that you're not seeing spaces at the end, which might be printed before hitting the stray "lucky `'\0'`".

A few other points:

- There's no need to write this using indexing.
- It's not very efficient to call `strlen()` on each loop iteration.
- You might want to use `isspace()` to remove more whitespace characters.

Here's how I would write it, using `isspace()` and pointers:

```
char * remove_spaces(char *str)
{
  char *ret = str, *put = str;

  for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
  {
    if(!isspace((unsigned char) *str)
      *put++ = *str;
  }
  *put = '\0';

  return ret;
}
```

Note that this *does* terminate the space-less version of the string, so the returned pointer is guaranteed to point at a valid string.

Comment: If `line` is a null terminated string, then `non_spaced` is guaranteed to be null terminated so it's no "lucky `\0`"

Answer (score 0):

The string parameter of your function is null-terminated, right?
And in the loop, the null character of the original string get also copied into the non spaced returned string. So the non spaced string is actually also null-terminated!

For your compiler, the null character is just another binary data that doesn't get any special treatment, but it's used by string APIs as a handy character to easily detect end of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<= strlen(line)`, the length of the `strlen(line)` include the `'\0'` so your program can work. You can use debug and run analysis.