# Reading string and integer from file in C

Tags: c

I have a file for marks of student as shown as below:

```
T1 T2 T3 HW1 HW2 HW3 HW4 PRJ 
47 17 50 10  10  10  10  68
20 41 40 15  10  10  10  80
```

but I don't know how the number of students in the class. I try to write a code to read the data from the file but I get infinite loop.

```
  char header[10];
  int data;
  int a;
  int nos=0;

  //READ HEADINGS OF THE TABLE
  while(fscanf(f1, "%s", header) != '\n')
  {
      printf("%s \t", header);
  }
  printf("\n");

  //READ DATA OF THE TABLE     
  while(fscanf(f1, "%d", data) != EOF)
  {
      for(a=0; a<=7; ++a)
      {
          printf("%d \t", data);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("Number of students in class: %d", nos/8); 
  system("pause");
```

Comment: Your assumptions about the nature of `fscanf()`s return value are incorrect. RTFM.

Comment: Why are you comparing `fscanf()`'s return value to `'\n'`, sorry to ask like this but Did you bother reading the documentation?

Comment: Rather than using loop like `while (foo() != one_of_several_values_that_cause_trouble)`, use  `while (foo() == the_one_value_code_expects)`.  IOWs: `while(fscanf(f1, "%d", data) == 1)`

Comment: @chux `while(fscanf(f1, "%d", &data) == 1)`

Comment: Compiler warnings are there for good reasons. Enable and pay heed to them! If your compiler still does not complain, you have a rubbish compiler. Trash it and get a modern one (i.e. less than 10 years old).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fscanf` returns the total number of arguments successfully matched so `fscanf(f1, "%s", header) != '\n'` will always be true as `-1 < 10` (EOF), `0 < 10` (Matching failure but not end of file) and also `1 < 10` (matched successfully). Here 10 is ASCII of `\n`.
2. Also in second `fscanf` instead of `data`, it should be `&data`.

Please read `man -s3 fscanf`.

Here correct solution will be:

```
#define HEADERS 8

char header[10];
int data, a, nos = 0;

for(a = 0; a < HEADERS; a++) //assuming there'll always be 8 headers
{
    fscanf(f1, "%s", header);
    printf("%s \t", header);
}
printf("\n");

while(fscanf(f1, "%d", &data) == 1)
{
    nos++;
    printf("%d \t", data);
    if(!(nos % HEADERS))
        printf("\n");
}

printf("Number of students in class: %d", nos/HEADERS);
```

Comment: `EOF` is not guaranteed to be `-1`. And this will result in an endless loop for invalid input.

Comment: @Olaf: I assumed the file to contain all valid data as posted by OP himself/herself at the beginning of the question.

Comment: This attitude is the reason for rubbish software which crashes if the input is not exactly as expected. Better is defensive programming.

Comment: @Olaf: Also yes EOF is not guaranteed to be -1 but it's guaranteed to be negative. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4705984/1783971 So here first `while` loop is an infinite loop as I said.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way is to read each line in full in a buffer and use `sscanf` to extract the names.

```
 #define N 100
 char buffer[N];
 fgets(buffer, N, f1);
 unsigned num_tasks = 0;
 while(sscanf(buffer, "%s", header) == 1) {
     printf("%s \t", header);
     num_tasks++;
 }
```

Do the same for each line of marks and count students along the way. Stop when `fgets()` returns EOF.