# add break statement in while loop with getchar

Tags: c, while-loop, break, getchar

i am a starter and i have written a code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char c;
char a[100]={0};
int i;

int main(void)
{   
  while(1)
  {
    i=0;
    while(1){
      if((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        a[i]=c;
        i++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("%s\n",a); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and now i have idea that i want to add a break statement that when i type q, the program will break. so my new program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char c;
char a[100]={0};
int i;

int main(void)
{   
  while(1)
  {
    i=0;
    while(1){
      if((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        a[i]=c;
        i++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("%s\n",a);
    if(getchar()=='q')break;       /*i added this*/
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i know because the getchar() conflict the code is not correct, how can i do, to add the type q break command. thanks a lot.

Comment: start by learning how to avoid using `global variables` when not need

Comment: @SeekAddo What do you mean *global*? Those variables have internal linkage, so they're not visible to other modules... Would you mind showing me where within [the C standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) I can find more information about *global variables*? I'd like to learn how to declare and use them...

Comment: @Seb Global variables can be accessed from anywhere in the application. They can be deemed bad practice by some, as the variables can be modified by another function. `char c; ` `char a[100]={0};` `int i;` were all defined outside the `main`. Any function within this application can access them for which is a bad practice

Comment: @SeekAddo Can those globals be accessed from *anywhere* within the application? How about prior to their declaration, e.g. `char return_c(void) { return c; }` followed immediately by `char c;`... Is that possible? Can those globals be accessed from other translation units? Do you understand what a translation unit is?

Comment: You said it yourself, *globals* are accessible *anywhere*... but you can see from my code, `c` isn't accessible *anywhere* despite being declared outside of functions, because it isn't accessible to functions declared *before* it! So none of these variables are globals, and C doesn't have globals. The other example is translation units; once you learn about using the linker, you'll find that none of these variables are accessible to modules linked using the linker... Further proof that C has no *global variables*. **But the ultimate proof is in the C standard, which I linked to earlier**...

Comment: @SeekAddo More importantly, you need to ask yourself in the future, *is this comment actually useful for this question*? The answer, as a rule of thumb, is: *most stylistic comments are useless*.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely to be what you actually want, but at least this will work

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a[100]={0};
  int i = 0;
  do {
    int c = getchar();
    switch (c) {
       case EOF:
           /*EOF*/
           return -1;
       case '\n':
           a[i] = 0;
           printf("%s\n",a);
           i= 0;
           break;
       default:
           a[i++] =c;
           break;
  } while (c != 'q' || i > 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `EOF` is guaranteed to be -1? Why inject the magic number, rather than just writing `EOF`?

Comment: I used -1 to illustrate that the `c` could not be of type char, but sure I could have written a longer explanation -- and yes, while EOF usually is -1, then [it is only guaranteed to be a negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706217/668501)

Comment: Also, contrary to your introduction ("Unlikely to be what you actually want"), I think this *is* likely to be what the OP asked for... so you've got +1 from me for that, and for your quasi-correct `getchar` error handling.

Answer (score 1):

> i am a starter and i have written a code

Uh oh! Here goes... Firstly, the odds of successfully learning the portable, standard-compliant C programming language are *overwhelmingly low* for anyone who tries to learn by unguided trial and error. There's a *really nice* book you can use as a guide, but you need to *read it* AND *do the exercises as you stumble across them*. That's K&R2E, if you're interested.

---

Anything resembling `char c; c = getchar();` is erroneous because the narrowing conversion from `int` (which `getchar` returns) to `char` discards error handling information.

Any character values returned by `getchar` will be as `unsigned char` values converted to an `int`, so it'd technically be *more correct* (though **still incorrect**) to use that type.

Error values are returned as a negative integer such as `EOF`, not to be confused with character values, which is exactly what your code does wrong by discarding the error information.

**`getchar` returns `int`, so store the value into an `int`**, then test for errors, *then*, if you must, convert it down to an `unsigned char`.

---

> and now i have idea that i want to add a break statement that when i type q, the program will break.

Following on from the previous discussion, such a requirement is superfluous, nonetheless *easy* to incorporate *if you're handling errors correctly*. Just insert an extra test to match against `q` into the error handling, and presto!

Nonetheless, the error handling most likely already solves this problem, as most OSes have a mechanism to *close `stdin`*, which would cause `getchar` to return `EOF`, thus triggering the error handling clause. This is typically achieved by pressing CTRL+d in Linux, or CTRL+z in Windows, for example.

---

In conclusion, providing you aren't already reading one, it seems a nice book about C isn't all that'd benefit you; a nice book about console scripting for your favourite Unix-like OS would also be highly beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define q 113  --> These values are coming from ASCII table.
#define Q 81 

int main(void)
{
    char ch = 0;
    do
    {
        ch = getchar();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case q:
                // your logic goes here
                exit(0);
            case Q:
                // your logic goes here
                exit(0);
            /* more cases can come here */
        }
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Soren, fixed. Also instead of `exit()`, we can still use `break` if there is some exit_flag or condition outside switch is required.