# What would be the difference between setting a struct sockaddr_in to 0 and '\0' using memset?

Tags: c

I have just started off with C socket programming. I have read that 0 as an integer constant, refers to a null pointer when compared with a pointer and '\0' refers to a null character, something that sets all the bits to 0. And, in the case concerning my question, I know I should probably be using '\0'. But I can see a lot of implementations that uses 0 instead. What would be the difference as such? 
I don't wanna go with whatever that works. I can't move on till I understand why. 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is value of EOF and '\0' in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705968/what-is-value-of-eof-and-0-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. They are equal.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Um, but 0 and '\0' are inherently different, right? Would it be possible to give a brief explanation as to why they are equal here?

Comment: They are always equal. That's just another way of representing the same thing, so that you can use it inside a string literal like so: `char c[] = "a\0b\0c";`. You could write it like `char c[] = {'a', 0, 'b', 0, 'c'}`. It will be exactly the same.

Comment: The character '0' is integer 48. Whereas the character '\0' is the integer 0.

Answer (score 2):

There will be absolutely no difference. Please use `0` since you zeroise memory and you don't want to underscore any nature of the memory like you would do, say, when comparing either element of a `char` array with `'\0'` to denote that you are looking for a *null character*.

To be more precise, `' '` is an expression which gives an integer constant which corresponds to the character specified. In this particular case, `'\0'` evaluates to the same integer - `0`. So, no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent.

But it is common to use `0` when working with integers, and `'\0'` when dealing with characters or bytes:

```
int n = 0;
char ch = '\0';
```

For pointers use `NULL` macro.

`memset` has following prototype:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Although `value` has `int` type, it is being interpreted as byte value. So there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

In C, character literals such as `'x'` have type `int`, which means `'\0'` and `0` are not just numerically equal, they are 100% equivalent semantically.  They are two different spellings of the same integer constant.  You can only tell the difference using a construct that inspects the spelling of tokens, such as the preprocessor's `#` and `##` operators.

(Yes, this means `'\0'` is a null pointer constant.)

Answer (score 1):

`char` is an integer type, it means that the characters you can use with the simple quotes like `'a'` are in reality integer values. I invite you to look for the `ascii`, you'll see the link between characters and integers.
You can do some easy tests with `printf()` :

```
printf("%c == %d == %c\n", 'A', 'A', 65);
```

You'll notice that the character `'\0'` has the integer value `0`, so there is no difference, you can use `0` or `'\0'` in your code, for the compiler it's the same thing.
Usually, `NULL` is a macro for `(void *) 0` wich is the value `0` casted into generic pointer (it's still the value `0`, but it will be interpreted as a pointer type).