# What does “~scanf” mean?

Tags: c

I saw it in a code like this

```
while(~scanf("%d",&a))
```

I know that `scanf()` has return value,but I can’t understand what does `~` mean

Comment: `~` is an operator: bitwise invert.

Comment: Given rici’s explanation, it Basically scans the first none zero integer to address of ‘a’

Comment: @RingØ Not quite. This stops at EOF, `!` would stop on any parse error, and not at EOF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a silly trick that relies on `EOF` having all its bits set. [Since the standard does not guarantee the exact value of EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4705968/335858), the behavior of this program is platform-dependent.

When `scanf` detects end-of-input, it returns `EOF`. Standard requires `EOF` to be negative. Very often `EOF` is set to `-1`. When `~` is applied to `-1`, you get back a zero, so the loop stops. On platforms with `EOF` defined as some other negative number the loop will never stop. Code's behavior also depends on the implementation-defined behavior of `~` with signed values.

You should rewrite the loop as follows:

```
while (scanf("%d", &a) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It also depends on implementation-dependent behavior of bitwise operators on signed values.

Comment: It also depends on the input being correct. Add a non-numeric character to the input and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @rici We don't know what he does inside the loop, though - he may be taking non-numerics off the input buffer, so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: So, to echo @rici's point, the loop condition should more likely be `while (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {  … }` so that it stops on error or EOF.  It doesn't make the code in the question any more sensible, though.  Without capturing the value returned by `scanf()` explicitly, the body of the `!= EOF` loop can't reliably detect whether a value was read or not: `while ((rc = scanf("%d", &a)) != EOF) { …code that checks rc before using a… }` would be OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's hard to say without seeing what he does inside the loop. I wanted to suggest `== 1` at the beginning, but that would not be equivalent to author's intended behavior (although I'd write `== 1` if it were my code :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: we know they don't save the value returned by scanf, which implies that they don't know whether a non-numeric value was present.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few knowledge tidbits that are needed to explain how this works and what it does.

**First: ~**

`~` is the bitwise `NOT` operator. It inverts the bits in a binary number.

ex:

```
1010111
0101000
```

**Second: scanf()**

If you look at the `man` pages for `scanf()`:

```
NAME
   scanf,  fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf 

   ...

RETURN VALUE
   These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
   event of an early matching failure.

   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
   the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
   for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
   error.
```

We can see that when `scanf()` is successful, it will return some integer equal to or greater than 0. If it reached `EOF` or was otherwise unsuccessful, it will return the (integer) value `EOF`.

**Third: the trick**

If you `NOT` most non-zero integers, you will still receive a non-zero value in return.
The exception to this would be a number than when represented in binary would be entirely `1`'s:

```
~11111111 = 00000000 = 0
```

As it turns out in most computer systems this happens to be the value `-1` *which just so happens to be the value typically assigned to `EOF`*

So

```
while(~scanf("%d",&a))
```

Could be re-written as

```
while(scanf("%d",&a) != -1)
```

or

```
while(scanf("%d",&a) != EOF)
```