# Why is my C program not printing out the string?

Tags: c, stack, malloc

I am am making a program that prints out what the user types in, and it needs to be done with the method `read_line()` (for my homework), so I can't change too much.

I don't understand why it isn't printing out what the user enters.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {
  char tempBuf[sz];
  char c;
  int pos = 0;

  printf("> ");

  while(1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (tempBuf[pos] == EOF || tempBuf[pos] == '\n') {
      buf = tempBuf;
      return buf;
    } else {
      tempBuf[pos] = c;
    }
    pos++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *buf;
  char *input = read_line(buf, 128);

  printf("Here: %s", input);
}
```

I am new to C and I am finding it very confusing, so please explain anything in pretty simple terms. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try compiling your code with diagnostic flags: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic yourfile.c` and try to solve the error/warnings one by one.

Comment: Your `read_line` function is broken. You must compare the return value of `getchar()` to `EOF`. But `tempBuf` only contains the return value of `getchar` after it's cast to a `char`, losing precision necessary for the comparison to EOF. It is very worrisome to me that you would get an assignment including code you may not change written by someone who doesn't understand how to use `getchar` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *buf;
char *input = read_line(buf, 128);
```

Your first line creates a pointer variable called `buf` but does not assign it any particular value. Your second line passes the value of `buf` to `read_line` -- but you never assigned it any particular value. So you passed garbage to `read_line` and told it to use that garbage as a buffer.

You might want `char buf[128];` instead of `char *buf;`, but it's hard to tell.

Also, please see my comment about your `read_line` function being broken in a way that indicates that whoever wrote it does not understand how to use `getchar`.

Comment: Also `stdio.h` is not included, making `EOF` and `printf` undeclared.

Comment: @Xatenev Depending on the environment `stdlib.h` includes `stdio.h`, so it would compile anyway

Comment: @ChatterOne Wasn't aware of that, thanks, I'll leave it though maybe its still useful for someone where that is not the case.

Comment: Looking at the other answers, it's much worse than I thought. The `read_line` function is hopelessly broken, returning garbage.

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes in your program.

For starters you are passing to the function an uninitialized pointer

```
char *buf;
char *input = read_line(buf, 128);
```

In fact there is no sense to pass the pointer value of which is not used in the function.

Within the function the variable c should be declared as having the type int.

```
int c;
```

Otherwise if the type char behaves as the type unsigned char (it depends on a compiler option) a comparison it with `EOF` will always evaluates to false.

Within the function the array tempBuf is not initialized. So this if statement

```
if (tempBuf[pos] == EOF || tempBuf[pos] == '\n') {
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Within the wjile llop you have to check that the value of `pos` is less than the value of `sz`.

The function returns a pointer to a local array that makes the returned pointer invalid.

```
  buf = tempBuf;
  return buf;
```

Moreover the array even does not contain a string because the terminating zero is not appended to the array.

The function should allocate dynamically memory and return pointer to the allocated memory that will contain a zero terminated string.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * read_line( size_t n ) 
{
    char *s = malloc( n );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        int c;

        printf( "> " );

        size_t i = 0;

        for ( ; i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++ )
        {
            s[i] = c;
        }

        s[i] = '\0';
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 128;

    char *input = read_line( n );

    if ( input != NULL ) printf( "Here: %s\n", input );

    free( input );

    return 0;
}
```

the program output might look like

```
> Hello Jake Jackson
Here: Hello Jake Jackson
```

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of `read_line` is very flawed due to the simple fact that it returns a locally declared buffer (which gets deleted at the end of the function). As a result, your pointers are pointing at garbage values (which is very dangerous - I repeat - as it will cause your program to crash or worse [keep running even when using memory it doesn't own]).

What you **should** be doing instead a dynamically creating the buffer on the heap (that way it can safely be returned - but it would have to be manually deleted).

So your function (and the rest of the code) should change to something like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *read_line(size_t sz) {
  // create a new buffer on the heap - so it can easily be returned (note this will have to be deleted after use using free()).
  char *tempBuf = malloc(sz);
  int c;
  int pos = 0;

  // set all elements of tempBuf to nulls
  memset(arr, 0, sz); 

  printf("> ");

  while(1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (tempBuf[pos] == EOF || tempBuf[pos] == '\n') {
      return tempBuf;
    } else {
      tempBuf[pos] = (char) c;
    }
    pos++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *input = read_line(128);    
  printf("Here: %s", input);

  // free the memory since we are now done with it.
  free(input);
}
```

You can read more about the heap & stack [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-overflow-stack-overflow/).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that isn't really necessary as `EOF` in most implementation has a value of `-1`, and since `char` is represented as a signed 8bit integer on many systems - it can perfectly store the value of `-1`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hence you really didn't have to downvote me. none at all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica mhhh okay. Please make the edit to my answer.

Comment: *that isn't really necessary as EOF in most implementation has a value of -1, and since char is represented as a signed 8bit integer on many systems - it can perfectly store the value of -1*  Ooof, that's a level of misunderstanding that's so bad it's not even wrong. The history has been deleted, so I don't know what happened, but... The `char` with the unsigned decimal value `255` is a legal `char` value that is `-1` in signed, twos-complement `char`, **but it's not `EOF`**.  `EOF` is deliberately chosen to be outside the range of values that a `char` can hold.

Comment: @AndrewHenle have you read this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705968/what-is-value-of-eof-and-0-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705968/what-is-value-of-eof-and-0-in-c)

Comment: @marvinIsSacul No. [I read this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1):  "`EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;"  `getchar()` returns **`int`** for a reason:  `EOF` can not be represented by a `char` value. Are you trying to argue that `(char) 255` should compare equal to `EOF`?  Because that's what you effectively did when you stated "that isn't really necessary as EOF ... it can perfectly store the value of -1"

Comment: (cont) When `getchar()` reads the **character** with the decimal value 255 or hex 0xFF, `getchar()` returns the `int` value `0x000000FF` to the caller (assuming 32-bit `int`).  When `getchar()` encounters end-of-file, assuming `EOF` is defined as `-1`, `getchar()` returns the `int` value `0xFFFFFFFF`.  Just because the `char` value `0xFF` expands to `-1` as an `int` (assuming signed `char`), that does not make the `char` with the value `0xFF` the same as `EOF`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. I understand now. I did some research regarding this.